# Select a connected object from a mask in ImageJ

Tags: imagej, morphological-analysis

I would like to use Fiji (ImageJ) for some simple pre-processing operation and to create a binary mask. I am just using the GUI and  I am not interested in an authomatic procedure. 
I got the following mask: (this is just a slice, the actual mask is 3 D, 298 MB)

[image: Original Mask]

I need to extract a 3D connected object, so that the result would be:

[image: Object Mask]

Ideally I would like to click inside a point inside the object with a 3D equivalent of the Wand tool, select the object, invert the selection, multiply by 0. For a start, I tried to use the command Analyze - 3D objects Counter, but I guess the image is too big and complex (the operation freezes at step 2. Connecting Objects). 
Is there any procedure I can follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Fiji you could do the following:

1. Invert the image with `Edit > Invert`.
2. Select the point selection tool from the Fiji toolbar.
3. Click in the region you want to extract the connected white pixels from, to place a point selection there.
4. Run `Plugins > Process > Find Connected Regions`.
5. Select `Start from point selection?` and change `Stop after this number of regions are found` to `1`.
6. Click `OK`.

There's [some documentation for that plugin](http://www.longair.net/edinburgh/imagej/find-connected-regions/) (which I wrote a long time ago).  It uses a very naive algorithm for finding connected regions, but it's good enough for many purposes.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! and plugin!